# Converting components with NSDateComponents

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an `NSDateComponent` that may contain indeterminate components. Sometimes days, sometimes hours or even a mixture of components.
What I would like to do is convert whatever is in my `doItAgainComp` down to seconds. Is there a way of doing this using the `NSDateComponent` class.

I would just divide them all out mathematically but I wont be able to do so for month components.

I've searched and have been unable to find anything on this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a NSDate from the components, then get the time interval from it :

```
NSDate * myDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:doItAgainComp];
NSTimeInterval time = [myDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: Didnt quite use you answer but It gave me the idea for this solution: `NSDateComponents *secondComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                                                                 fromDate:selectedStartDate
                                                                                   toDate:recurringDate
                                                                                  options:0];
`

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but maybe you can use the `timeIntervalSince1970` method to determine the seconds since 1 JAN 1970. So if you set the year as 1970 and then convert the `NSDateComponent` to an `NSDate` using `NSCalendar`'s `dateFromComponents:` it should work.